# Realtime Database Security Rules no access on root directoy

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

We have a basic cloud storage app that now supports shared files.  However, when writing the rules, I ran into an issue:

using the wildcard $file, one could use the JS Console to load into a folder (node) one has access to, but when trying to access the root files directory, it would not load any files, instead of loading the nodes one has access to.  The problem lies in that there is no read, write rules on the root directory, and the function to render requires grabbing the value of that directory, which then loads the files in the directory.

I was wondering if there was a way that grabbing the value of the directory would return a value containing only the files one has access to?

What i mean is that:

```
firebase.database().ref('/shared-files/shared/files/').on('value', (snapshot) => {
alert(snapshot.val())
})
```

would alert the json for the files you have access to, excluding the ones you don't.
The current rules for the shared files are below, the root directory for shared files is located at /shared-files/shared/files/

```
    "shared-files": {
      "shared": {
        "files": {
          "$file": {
                ".read":"root.child('shared-files').child('shared').child('files').child($file).child('users').hasChild(auth.token.email.replace('@forcloud.app',''))",
                ".write":"(root.child('shared-files').child('shared').child('files').child($file).child('users').hasChild(auth.token.email.replace('@forcloud.app',''))) || newData.exists()"
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you're hoping to filter the children under /shared-files/shared/files to only specific ones the user has access to.  The way you're doing it now, it's not possible.  [Security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters).  If any of the children would be denied access, then the entire read fails.

What you'll have to do instead is organize your data in such a way that the client can query for only the items that they know they should have access to, based on the logic in the rules.  The client filter will have to match the limits applied by the security rules.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  Would using Query-based rules work?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  I suggest reading that link to the docs first thing.

Comment: Yes, I found a section in the docs that says Query-based rules, which seems to be what I'm looking for